# How to make mobile <select> allow typing an option instead of selecting one.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Suppose I have a the following selection options:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

On a PC I can select "audi" by typing "a". But on a mobile device I have to scroll and select "audi". Is there a way to make mobile devices use a qwerty keyboard instead of a scroll list?

Comment: You'd have to focus the element without "tapping" on it, which doesn't sound like something that can be done in a mobile UI.  And you'd have to have a keyboard available when the element is focused, which most mobile platforms currently don't do.

Comment: Have you looked at the [`<datalist>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) element?

Comment: A note on <datalist>, datalist is not supported on safari and has support only in latest browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is **not** possible. Instead, you can use `autocomplete` from jQuery UI to achieve the same.

Try this https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

[EDIT] `<Datalist>` is also there. But, trust me, it is real slow for larger list of options.